# display search result with jquery on smarty template

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, smarty

I am trying to display a search result in a `<div>` on a smarty template.
The search result is taken from a click.

The anchor is this:

```
<li class="price-list-item"><a href="javascript:void();" class="price" onclick="searchRange(0,1000)">0-1000</a></li>
```

and the searchRange function is this:

```
function searchRange(first, second) {    
    var first = first;
    var second = (second != null) ? second : first; 
    $("#ad-display").load("index.php?first="+first+"&second="+second+" #ad-display");
}
```

the ad-display box that are written in `adlistdisplay.tpl` looks like this:

```
<div id="ad-display">
    <section id="add-list">
        <ul id="ad-list">
        {foreach from=$adverts key=k item=i name=ad_list}
            <li class="ad-list-item-{cycle values="odd,even"}" id="ad-{$i.aid}">
                <div class="ad-item-box">
                    <div class="ad-item-photo">
                        <a href="viewad.php?aid={$i.aid}"><img src="adimages/{$i.img}" width="80" height="80"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ad-item-info">
                        <span class="ad-item-title"><a href="viewad.php?aid={$i.aid}">{$i.title}</a></span>
                        <span class="ad-item-desc">{$i.text|truncate:25}</span>
                        <span class="ad-item-price">Kr. {$i.price|number_format:2:",":"."}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>  
        {/foreach}
        </ul>                            
    </section>
</div>
```

in my index.php I have this code:

```
$adverts = new Adverts();
$smarty->assign('catlist', $adverts->getcategories());
SmartyPaginate::assign($smarty);

if(isset($_GET["first"])) {
    $search = new SearchEngine();    
    $smarty->assign('adverts', $search->search_ads(null, "price", $_GET["first"], $_GET["second"]));    
} else {
    $smarty->assign('adverts', $adverts->listadverts());    
}

$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

index.tpl contains this:

```
{include file="adlistdisplay.tpl"}
```

When I click the anchor at the top, it just shows a blank spot at #ad-display. No results are displayed.
I want it to display the result from search_ads function. It look like this:

```
function search_ads($search_string = null, $type, $min_price = null, $max_price = null) {

        global $db;
        global $config;

        switch($type) {
            case "text":
                $search = 'text LIKE "%'. $search_string .'%"';
                break;
            case "price":
                $search = 'price > '. $min_price .' <= '. $max_price .'';
                break;
            case "headline":
                $search = 'title LIKE "%'. $search_string .'%"';
                break;
            default:
                $search = 'price BETWEEN '. $min_price .' AND '. $max_price .'';
                break;
        }

        $row = $db->dbh->query('SELECT ad.*, (SELECT img.image FROM '.$config->db_prefix.'_images img WHERE img.aid = ad.aid LIMIT 1) AS img FROM '.$config->db_prefix.'_adverts ad WHERE '. $search .' AND ad.approved = 1');        
        $row->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $row;
    }
```

I have created this fiddle to show what I to achieve. It is a little different, but shows my intention

http://jsfiddle.net/xeAkY/20/

SOLUTION:

```
$search = 'price > '. $min_price .' AND price <= '. $max_price .'';
```

Comment: There's an awful lot of code for us to wade through here. Have you tried simplifying your problem down so there aren't so many components where the error might be?

Comment: I agree. Your problem seems to be hidden behind too much information. You fetch the data using [jquerys load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Have you debugged if your server sends you some data back (p.e. with firebug or something similar)?

Comment: Sorry about the code - I thought I would provide as much connected code as possible.
I believe the problem is somewhere between the search result and the loading into the div. It do pass the parameters the the search function.

Comment: Setting the correct query helps alot! :) I missed 'AND price <=' in the search query!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution posted at the bottom of the question